# Word document -select text and context menu - best way?

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word, ms-office

This is my user case:

1. I need to display the Word document in my WPF app.
2. Select a word, phrase, paragraph.
3. For the selected text, display the context menu with actions.

So far I've found one way - use Word(ms-office).
But maybe you can tell me a library (free) that will do it.
This would be more optimal.

Comment: Asking for tools is off topic, but I can see that you need help knowing where to look so here: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/features/office-tools/

Comment: For me, a separate library is better - I found Synscfusion DocIo for WPF - but it does not allow creating a shortcut menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question: I found this [component](https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/sfrichtextboxadv/overview). This is what you need.